# iPhone: Default compiler directive in Objective C

Tags: iphone

If this question is repeated, please ignore it. but i couldn't find it repeated. In objective C, the default compiler directive is @protected not @public for class instance variables, is that right? Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [By] default, instance variables are visible in all instance methods of a class and its subclasses. This is referred to as @protected scope in Objective-C.

- [Objective-C Tuesdays: instance variables](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/04/objective-c-tuesdays-instance-variables.html)

Comment: Note, however, that this only applies to instance variables declared in the header. If you've declared it as part of the `@implementation` it will not be visible to other compilation units at all.

Answer (score 0):

All instance variables without an explicit scope directive have @protected scope